# Apply SQL Function to a Table Column Values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-function

I have a Transact SQL function `SimpleSplit`, which splits a string according to the delimiter. I can use it as follows:

```
 DECLARE @DelimitedString NVARCHAR(128)
 SET @DelimitedString = 'Processor,RAM,SSD,Ethernet'
 SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SimpleSplit](@DelimitedString, ',')
```

This results in:

```
Processor
RAM
SSD
Ethernet
```

As expected.

I now have a Table called `PROD_TABLE` with a column `Descr`. I would like to apply this function to each value in column `Descr`. I attempted the following and it does not work:

```
SELECT p.[ID], p.[Descr]
FROM [Amazon].[dbo].[PROD_TABLE] p
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[SimpleSplit](p.Descr, '-') d
```

In the output I only see the `ID` and the `Descr` Columns i.e. no results from the `SimpleSplit` function. However, if I attempt

```
SELECT *
FROM [Amazon].[dbo].[PROD_TABLE] p
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[SimpleSplit](p.Descr, '-') d
```

I see the results of the `SimpleSplit` function in the last column. Why does this query apply the function, but the previous query does not?

**Answer**

Thanks to **mr.Rebands** answer below, I realized that I needed to name the results. Hence * worked, but to explicitly name the columns I needed to do something like:

```
SELECT p.[ID], p.[Descr], d.[Data]
FROM [Amazon].[dbo].[PROD_TABLE] p
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[SimpleSplit](p.[Descr], '-') d
```

Comment: Your function returns a table - what is the column name of the `SimpleSplit` result table?  Don't you have to include that column name in your select statement?  `OUTER APPLY` is applied but the results not selected.

Comment: Wow **mr.Reband**. Thank you for your quick reply. I wish you had put your comment as an answer, so that I could mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns a table - what is the column name of the `SimpleSplit` result table?  You will have to include that column name in your select statement.

`OUTER APPLY` is applied but the results are not selected.